# Update join tabla oracle sql

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy tratado de actualizar la columna de la tabla EMPLEADOS con los registros de otra tabla NOMBRES_U

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo la sentencia update

```
UPDATE (SELECT a.nombre, b.nombre_usuarios
         FROM empleados a
         JOIN nombres_u b ON a.empleadoid = b.id)
   SET nombre = nombre_usuarios;
```

el problema que tengo es que en la tabla nombres usuarios solo tengo 10 registros y en la tabla empleados tengo 16 y quiero que los registros si se repitan.

como puedo hacer que los registros se actualicen consecutivamente

Comment: La única forma en la que se me ocurre realizar lo que planteas es mediante el uso de un cursor.

Comment: Es necesario usar un cursor o una CTE

Comment: Tendrán algún ejemplo, documentación o liga donde pueda buscar la solución, se agradece el apoyo

Comment: No comprendo que quieres decir con que los registros si se repitan....